# Not getting push messages from gcm server to my android device?

Tags: android, push-notification

Hi In my project I added gcm notification services.I sent device unique id to server my key also matches server key.But i didn't get any push notifications to my device.Please provide any suggestions. Thanks in advance.

Comment: what have u tried so far?? post ur code...

Comment: I followed developers link and given all permissions in Manifest  file.

Comment: r u testing on emulator?

Comment: no am testing in device only.

Comment: Have you checked that your registration id store in your database?